# Kentico V8 custom slider web part

Tags: jquery, kentico

I don't have a very strong dotNet background, as i'm primary a JS/CSS guy.

I want to use slick.js as a slider plugin, but i'm lost one how. I'm wondering if i'm on the right track here.

Ideally, an editor would be able to create a new page based on a slider template i create each. Each page would be a new slide. These pages would be in a specific folder in the site tree.

My web part would then pull these pages in and render the correctly formatted code and include the needed JS.

Am i on the right tract here? And if so how do i start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're absolutely on the right track.  I've used slick on a couple of sites now and followed this pattern:

- Setup a repeater webpart
- Set the repeater's HTML envelope to be your slider's wrapper
- Set the repeater's transformation to repeat the content of the documents you want to repeat as slides
- Setup your slider script in a javascript webpart OR (my preferred method) on the page template's markup

Here's an example implementation in Kentico that uses slick's documentation.  I'm using version 7, so things will look a little bit different and be in different places, but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out where to go with some googling

First off, you'll need to get the css for slick.  Here I've just added it to the CSS file applied to this site in Kentico.:

[image: slick.css added to Kentico stylesheet]

---

Next you need to setup your page template:

[image]

Then add a repeater in the design tab:

[image]

And setup the repeater's HTML Envelope like so:

[image]

Finally, create your transformation:

[image]

Edit:  You'll also need to make sure you've setup your content properly, and made sure your repeater's content settings are pointed to the right path.  Here I've set the repeater up to pull everything from underneath the current path `./%` which is the slick document.

[image]

It's pulling in the test documents which you see here:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer Jerreck, even with the v7 screenshots :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks Jerreck. I'm working on this today. I may reach out if/when i stumble.

Comment: This is great. The only part that doesn't work for me is due to the transformation. While i see from the screen shots it loads the document name, it's the document content i can't get to display. So far so good!

Comment: @MarkHandy what content are you having trouble displaying?

Comment: @jerrick I don't see the lorem ispsum from the slide page.

The pages i have set as slides are a simple portal template, one zone with a editabletext webpart. I'm going to go through your steps and see if i missed something.

Comment: @MarkHandy Ah, that's probably your problem.  Accessing data from an editable text webpart is a little bit different from pulling it from a structured document type.  Although you can use a macro to do that http://devnet.kentico.com/questions/editableitems-editableregionid , it's much easier to setup a document type and resolve the values of the document's fields.

Comment: @jerrick Thanks. I'll rework how i'm doing the slide pages.

Comment: @jerrick I got it working. At least to a point where i now know what i'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What you do is add your JS files to the JavaScript application under a folder with your site's code name.  So if your site's code name is "MySite" then you open the JavaScript application in Kentico and add a new folder named "MySite" under the Custom folder.  Then upload your JS files in there.

On your page template, add a reference to your JS files using the JavaScript webpart and some code like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CMSPages/GetResource.aspx?scriptfile=/CMSScripts/Custom/MySite/my-js-file.js"></script>
```

Also include jQuery library if you need to.

Then Add a repeater webpart to your page template.  In the properties, you'll want to set the following properties:

- Path: the path to pickup the slider/images
- Page types: the page type you will be looking for in the path (ie: menu item)
- ORDER BY expression: NodeLevel, NodeOrder, NodeName
- Transformation: should be the transformation for each item in your slider.  For instance if you have an unordered list, this would include the opening and closing `<li>` tags and all their contents.
- Content before and after with the opening and closing tags for the unordered list as well as any wrapper elements you might need.

This should get you started.

Comment: Hi Brenden, when setting the ORDER BY by I've often used NodeLevel, NodeOrder but never bothered using NodeName, should I? Can you get more than one item on the same NodeLevel and NodeOrder? Is this to help with a Path like /%

Comment: Hey @DarrenS by adding the NodeName, it will order the node items alphabetically after the level and order.  I always use it and it's Kentico recommended for ordering by what your content tree is setup like.  And yes, you can have multiple items with the same or similar names in the node, the alias will be different for the actual URL but the name can be the same.

Comment: Thanks as always Brenden.

Answer (score 0):

Could be done using custom page types for each slide and using a repeater and transformation. Set the path in the repeater to the folder containing your pages, Then just add the javascript file to your page.

Might want to check out [Writing Transformations Documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Writing+transformations)